# In Angular, is it Possible to have multiple CSS selectors?

Tags: css, angular, css-selectors

Doing this(below) will select only navbar.css.
What if I want to use multiple css files?

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.css']
})
```

Answer (score 1):

you can link multiple CSS classes to a component. As StyleUrls is an array we can write multiple entries as a comma-separated

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.css','./navbar2.component.css']
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.css', 'every css url you want']
```